are invariant subspaces under a bijective linear transformation the same?
if $f$ is a bijective linear transformation of the vector space $\mathcal{V}$, does it hold true that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ have the same invariant subspaces? My book has this as an exercise and im confused as to why that should work in the case of an infinite dimensional vector space. In fact i feel like i got a counterexample:
let V be the vector space of sequences in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
let elements be of the form $v:=(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, a_3, b_3,...)$
Then the linear map $f$, definied by $ v \mapsto (a_1, b_1, b_2, b_3, a_2, b_4 ,b_5, b_6, a_3, b_7. b_8, b_9, ...)$ is bijective. Let $U$ be the subspace $(X_1, 0, X_2, 0, X_3, 0, ...)$ for arbitrary $X_i \in \{0,1\}$. it is apparent now, that $f(U) \subset U$, however $f^{-1}(U) \not \subset U$, as for example $f^{-1}(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,...)=(0,0,0,1,0,0,...) \not \in U$
was this understandable? where is the mistake, or is the problem actually wrong? glad for any help!
Edit: as there now is another counter example in the comments, i conclude that the exercise is indeed wrong, the author probably just missed this case.

Can you perhaps quote this exercise from your book? Are there any assumptions such as $\mathcal V$ is finite dimensional? Or maybe it is a prove if it is true or false question, in which case you have your counterexample.

Use the dimension in the finite dimension case

im aware of how to prove the finite dimensional case, its just this infinite dimensional one thats bugging me. The exercise is from the german Book "Lineare Algebra" by Liesen and Mehrmann,
here is the quote of the exercise: "Sei V ein K-Vektorraum und f ∈ L(V, V) bijektiv. Zeigen Sie, dass f und f^-1 die gleichen invarianten Unterräume besitzen",
DeepL translation: "Let V be a K -vector space and f ∈ L(V, V) bijective. Show that f and f^-1 have the same
have the same invariant subspaces". Exercise 14.3

I think I have a counterexample using $ V= { f \in C^\infty (\mathbb R) \mid \forall k \in \mathbb N,, f^{(k)}(0)=0}$ and $\partial$ alongside with its inverse $f\mapsto (x\mapsto \int_0^x f)$ and the subspace $W = \mathbb R[x] \cdot e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} $

Sorry I forgot it was actually $\mathbb R [x^{-1}]$

So either there is a mistake in the book or you did not see some finiteness of the subspace in the statement (maybe earlier)

finiteness isnt stated at all near the question, the author probably just forgot that while writing down that exercise :)

It may happen that a linear operator $T$ is bijective yet its restriction to an invariant subspace $W$ is not surjective (though it's necessarily injective). Thinking along this line, it's easy to find simple examples.
Let $V$ be the algebra of Laurent polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ i.e., $\mathbb Q[x,x^{-1}]$.
The linear map $T\colon\,V\to V$ given by $f(x)\mapsto xf(x)$ is bijective. $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$. Check that $T\big|_{\mathbb Q[x]}$ is injective but not surjective since constant polynomials don't have a pre-image in $\mathbb Q[x]$.
This means that $\mathbb Q[x]$ won't be $T^{-1}$-invariant. The $T^{-1}$ map is given by $f(x)\mapsto x^{-1}f(x)$ and $T^{-1}(1)=x^{-1}\notin \mathbb Q[x]$.
